# Using Stream StreamSupplier

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

I'm using following code to reuse Stream but getting

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed

Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        String[] array = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
        Stream<String> ss = Stream.of(array);
        Supplier<Stream<String>> streamSupplier = () -> ss;

        long count = streamSupplier.get().count();
        // get new stream
        streamSupplier.get().forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));

        // get another new stream

        System.out.println(count);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What about `long count = streamSupplier.get().peek(System.out::println).count();
    System.out.println(count);`

Comment: in case, If i am using Spring Data to get stream of data from data source in the try with resource. In that case how will i use Supplier?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't assign `Stream.of(array)` to an intermediate variable, just return it directly in the `Supplier`:

```
Supplier<Stream<String>> streamSupplier = () -> Stream.of(array);
```

That is because previously you would just always supply the same *reference* when calling `supplier.get()` but in fact you wanted to return a new `Stream`.

Also as @Eugene suggested, using `Arrays.stream()` over `Stream.of()` is preferred. As the latter is a varargs method, but just delegates to the former.

---

Also your current approach can be simplified using the [`Stream.peek()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) method:

```
long count = Arrays.stream(array)
    .peek(System.out::println)
    .count();
```

Comment: was about to type the same thing... one small adjustment `Arrays.stream` instead of `Stream.of` saves one extra method call

Comment: You were faster with `peek`, have my +1.

Comment: @Lino In case, If i am using Spring Data JPA to get stream of data from data source in the try with resource. In that case how will i use Supplier?

Comment: @NishantKumar you can do something similar: `Supplier<Stream<String>> streamSupplier = () -> yourRepository.yourMethod();`.

Answer (score 4):

[`Stream::count`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--) is the [terminal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) operation which closes the Stream, so no more pipelines can proceed.

You create the `Stream<String>` before you put it to the `Supplier`. If you want the Supplier to provide a new Stream witch each call, create the `Stream<String>` directly in the `Supplier`.

```
Supplier<Stream<String>> streamSupplier = () -> Stream.of(array);
```

Then `streamSupplier.get()` will always work with the new `Stream<Stream>`.

---

Yet, you might achieve the same result with [`Stream::peek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) which works the same like `Stream::forEach` with an exception that it doesn't close the `Stream` but returns the same unmodified one (@Lino was faster).

```
long count = streamSupplier.get().peek(System.out::println).count();
```

Comment: As stated in the docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html

Answer (score 2):

The exception you're getting is appropriate and tells you what you need to research. From the [Java 8 Stream class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

> A stream should be operated on (invoking an intermediate or terminal
>   stream operation) only once. This rules out, for example, "forked"
>   streams, where the same source feeds two or more pipelines, or
>   multiple traversals of the same stream. A stream implementation may
>   throw IllegalStateException if it detects that the stream is being
>   reused. However, since some stream operations may return their
>   receiver rather than a new stream object, it may not be possible to
>   detect reuse in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

You're still using the same Stream over and over again. Move the `Stream.of(array)` within the supplier, not outside.